# Unable to connect to MASTER: Resource temporarily unavailable : Connecting to MASTER no:0

Tags: cluster, replication, redis, keepalived

I'm currently working on simle active stand/by Redis clustering for query caching with Keepalived.

[image]

The problem I'm facing is when I shutdown&start(restart) the host1 server for testing, it should keep the exact same virtual ip, and start replication with host2.
But syslog outputs "**Unable to connect to MASTER: Resource temporarily unavailable : Connecting to MASTER no:0", and fail the replication.**"

I assumed that would be happened because of OOM, and the kernel might kill the process.
So I implement these below refering the Redis set-up hints (https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=redis+administrator&oq=redis+administrator+&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.4847j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8).

- vm.overcommit _memory = 1
- set up swap file
- made sure that I have enough amount of memory for redis ( 2 times  the memory usually used )

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: You've to provide at least the involved configs... Additional note: The image is quite small, it's hard to read anything in there...

Comment: can u provide me keepalivde config file? and host1 , host2 both server keepalived config file,